# How to detect single control keyup event but not key combinations?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

It is easy to detect <kbd>control</kbd> key event with

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', handler, false);

...

function handler(e) {
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

    if (key == 17) { // Control key
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that any key combinations such as <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> will also trigger the event, and it seems that the event handler cannot distinguish between a single <kbd>control</kbd> and the <kbd>control</kbd> within a <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.

What I want is to allow only a single key press-and-release, but not a key combination, to trigger the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use `e.ctrlKey` and `e.altKey`, and the value will be true or false based on whether or not those keys are pressed.

In your event, it would be something like:

```
if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
    return;
}
```

**EDIT**

For reference, you can view https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey.

This property is actually a boolean that returns whether or not the ctrl key was pressed when the event was fired.

Then, you can see that if the user decides to press the ctrl key and no other key, this method will not return and e.ctrlKey will be false, since by the time the keyUp event was fired the user had already released the key.

Comment: The important bit here is `e.ctrlKey` will return true for onKeyup ONLY if pressed in combination with another key - see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ragdata/nwsm5Lgu/) for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```js
var controlConsidered = false;

function ctrlPressed() {
  console.log("Control was pressed.");
}

function keydownhandler(e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  controlConsidered = (key == 17);
}

function keyuphandler(e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key == 17 && controlConsidered) {
    ctrlPressed();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', keydownhandler, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyuphandler, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was not exactly asked, but for the curious, the following code can handle **both single control key presses and double control key presses**. It works as follows:

1. detects a valid single control key event exactly as described in [Josiah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33060973/2675672). If detected, fires `ctrlPressed`, which:
2. tracks the two previous timestamps at which a control key was pressed,
3. initializes a timeout for a particular `threshold` value (in milliseconds) every time it is fired, and,
4. if there is a control double click (the timestamp difference is within the threshold), the previous timeout is cancelled, else it isn't.

```js
var lastControlTime = 0,
  newControlTime, timeout,
  threshold = 200;

function ctrlPressed() {
  newControlTime = new Date();

  var bool = newControlTime - lastControlTime <= threshold;

  if (!bool)
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      if (timeout) {
        alert("Single control key pressed");
        timeout = undefined;
      }
    }, threshold);

  if (bool) {
    alert("Double control key pressed");
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = undefined;
  }

  lastControlTime = newControlTime;
}

function keydownhandler(e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  controlConsidered = (key == 17);
}

function keyuphandler(e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key == 17 && controlConsidered) {
    ctrlPressed();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', keydownhandler, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyuphandler, false);
```